# RecylerView.Adapter - notifyItemRemoved and notifyItemRangeChanged?

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have RecyclerView.Adapter class with the function:

```
private void removeItem(int position) {
    data.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    //notifyItemRangeChanged(position, data.size());
}
```

Do we also need to call the `notifyItemRangeChanged` function after `notifyItemRemoved`? I found a few tutorials/posts where peopole was using both of them but code works ok with `notifyItemRemoved` only.

Comment: No you don't need to use both of them

Comment: notifyItemRemoved reflects only item remove of position and notifyDataSetChanged reflects any data set change. More - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html